# Android Webview Question: How to open different pages with different buttons in single activity

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am pretty new to coding in android. I am making a companion app for the game DOTA 2. The layout has heaps of buttons and I want to utilize the Webview function to load different web pages for different heroes. Tutorials seemed to indicate that only one web page can be opened. I would have to create hundreds of pages to accommodate different heroes.

Question:
How to make each button open a different page when pressed?

Current code:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.loadUrl("http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Abaddon");
```

I have 113 web pages I need to open which corresponds to different heroes.

I hope this isn't an overload and it's not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

First for all it isn't a stupid question. Do you know some html? Because you can open all 113 web pages through html of JS to create less html pages. Can you show me your mainActivity.java?

You will need to edit your MainActivity to this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
```

public class StrHeroInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_str_hero_info);

    WebView swebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_str_hero);
    swebView.loadUrl("http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Abaddon");
    swebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocas) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocas);
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    if (hasFocas) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
}
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:") || url.startsWith("market:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
        view.goBack(); //method goback()
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Explenation

why function shouldOverrideUrlLoading:

You need this otherwise you can't load any other pages in the webview.

why function onKeyDown:

You need this if you want that people can use the key back on their phone:

Only thing that you then need to do is that you click the image that you go to an other page?

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time out to help me :). I know a little bit of html but not heaps. [**Here**](https://pastebin.com/ZLmuYbgP) is my MainActivity.java. It's too big to fit in the reply so i put it on pastebin.

Comment: You could edit your question and pasted there then. But It is okey with the pastebin. I don't see where you load your HTML page? Can you maybe show a screenshot how one page with a hero would look like?

Comment: [**This**](http://imgur.com/a/4j79x) is what it looks like. [**This**](https://pastebin.com/dX72BdWc) is my code that opens the html page.

Comment: Thanks, for taking the time to write up. I will test this and get back to you. I am currently undergoing exams so I won't be able to test it for a few weeks though.

Comment: And yes, I need to be able to click on an image and that links to a different page.

Comment: Okey let me know if it will work. Take your time and good luck with your exams!